# C generate unique id

Tags: c, dictionary, unique, wrapper

I am creating a C wrapper that can read types of data structures stored in text files. The interface should be that I can generate a unique id mapped to a unique data structure and modify through wrapper functions via the unique id.

The problem is that I need to be able to generate a unique id to map. I would like to not use any external library. Is there any way to do this without any large overhead?

Comment: how about 1, 2, 3, 4, ...?

Comment: Why don't you want to use external libraries? On which operating system are you coding? How unique should the `id` be (world-wide unique, system-wide unique, or process-wide unique)? Please **edit your question** to improve it!

Comment: Windows. I choose not to use external libraries due to the fact that it makes the library "bulkier". I would like to keeps things small, simple, and compatible.

Comment: use `time()` + `rand()`

Comment: and that's how you gain *5* upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you are wanting the id to be (practically speaking) world-wide unique (so two processes running your program on two different computers on two different machines would always have different ids).

<sup>Otherwise, just use a `static long counter;` then `id = counter++;` in your wrapper.</sup>

You might use [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s for that purpose.

Or you could generate a random -e.g. 24 bytes- string (or two or three random `uint64_t` numbers). If your numbers are "enough" random (at least if you seed a good [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) with a random seed at startup time, e.g. using a random source à la [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) (or [getrandom(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html)) or the current time & process id & host id; be sure to use a PRNG with a big enough state) the probability of [collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29) should be negligible (but I am not able or willing to quantify it).

FWIW, in my [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) monitor, I am doing similar things (on Linux) in routine `mom_make_random_idstr` of my file [random.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/blob/master/random.c); the random string contains a nicely restricted set of characters (compatible with C identifiers). Look also inside [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/)'s [id_BM.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/id_BM.c) file and the `randomid_BM` & `idtocbuf32_BM` or inside [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/).

You could also take some inspiration from MongoDb [objids](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1375314/841108).