# Unique String generator

Tags: c

I want to make a program (network server-client).
One of the specification for this program is next:

The server will receive the sent packages and save it into a file, with a unique name (generated by the server at the moment the transfer starts.
Ex __tf_"unique_random_string".txt

I made a function that returns a pointer to a "unique" string created.

The problem is: If i stop the server and then start it again it will generate the same names.

Ex:this file names were generated and then i stopped the server.

__ft_apqfwk.txt

__ft_arzowk.txt

__ft_cdyggx.txt

I start it again and i try to generate 3 file names. Them will be the same.

Sorry for my english. I'm still learning it.

My function to generate this "unique string" is:

```
char *create_random_name(void)
{
    const char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char *file_name;
    int i=0;
    int key;
    if((file_name = malloc(16 * sizeof ( char )) ) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to alloc memory space\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(file_name,"__ft_");
    for(i=5 ; i<11 ; i++)
    {
        key = rand() % (int)(sizeof(charset)-1);
        file_name[i]=charset[key];
    }
    strcat(file_name,".txt");
    file_name[15] = '\0';
    return file_name;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour present in code. `file_name[16]` _isn't a valid index_ . You allocate `16` byte so indexing should be from `0 to 15` and leave index `15` also if you pass `file_name` to string manipulation functions.

Comment: Can you please explain more. I don't understand what you want to say.

Comment: Can you please help me with this. I already googled it for hours and i didn't found a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've made that modify but i still have the problem that i asked here

Comment: You might want to check out these questions about generating unique names: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250067/c-generate-unique-id) and [also here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375314/simple-generation-of-guid-in-c)

Comment: That was just a problem you would eventually encounter I pointed . But hardly it would have corrected problem with random generation  .

Comment: Using `rand()` creates a false sense of _pointer to a "unique" string_.

If code truly wants to create a unique string, it needs to create a _state_ saved outside the code. E.g. a file.

Comment: Be aware that with 6 random characters from lowercase letters you can only make 308,915,776 different strings; and that you will get a repetition very much sooner than you probably expect.

Comment: @pmg: Luckily, at least for `mkstemp`/`mkstemps`, the set of characters is the [POSIX portable filename character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_276), which increases the options per position from 26 to 65, or 75,418,890,625 total possible fills. You'd use over 490 GB (GiB to use the hated but precise unit) just storing six characters plus a single byte (for length or `NUL` terminator), ignoring the rest of the filesystem overhead and the actual data, before you made that many files, so you're unlikely to run into the issue. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's available, you could avoid manually generating random names that might collide and let the system do it for you (and handle collision resolution by creating a new name) by using [`mkstemps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html). This is also safer because it opens the file for you, removing the risk of a random name being generated, verified to be unique, then trying to open it and discovering another thread/process raced in and created it.

```
char name[] = "/path/to/put/files/in/__ft_XXXXXX.txt";
int fd = mkstemps(name, strlen(".txt"));
if (fd == -1) { ... handle error ... }
```

After `mkstemps` succeeds, `name` will hold the path to the file (it's mutated in place, replacing the `XXXXXX` string), and `fd` will be an open file descriptor to that newly created file; if you need a `FILE*`, use [`fdopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) to convert to a `stdio` type.

Comment: After many tests. I deleted that function and i used your advice. I think this is the best solution for unix systems i think.

Answer (score 2):

One option is saving to a file the names that have been used, and using them as a checklist. You also want to seed rand with something like `srand(time(NULL))`.

another is ignoring the randomisation, and just going in order, e.g. aaa, aab aac...aba ,abb etc. Again, save where your cycle is up to on a file.

Comment: this srand function might be the correct answer. I tested with it and i think the problem is solved. I hope it will not appear anymore

Comment: srand will not solve it on its own though- it will stop the rand() cycle from starting at the same point every time, but as has been pointed out, you can theoretically get the same code a second time without having checks that it hasn't been used.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems a little bit unclear but if you want to generate a unique string there are a couple of things you can consider:

1. Get System timestamp ( yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-fff-tt)
2. Use Random function to generate a random number

Combine this with your function and I am sure you will get a unique string.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hello. I used srand function and now it works. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling rand(),--- once and only once---, call srand(time()) to initialize the random number generator.

Before settling on any specific file name, call stat() to assure that file name does not already exist.